# Mobile navigation - off-canvas or dropdown?

Tags: mobile, navigation, dropdown, off-canvas, responsive

I'm working on a responsive site where the main navigation gets compressed to a "menu" button when at a mobile small-screen size. I feel like there are 2 strong methods for handling the navigation:

1. **Off-canvas** -- menu pushes the page content to the right so that only a small portion is showing. Many apps (like Facebook) use this technique, as does Indochino (http://www.indochino.com).
2. **Dropdown** -- menu comes down vertically (sometimes pushes page content down, sometimes covers page content). This seems slightly more common than off-canvas -- an example is Nokia (http://www.nokia.com).

I'm struggling to see a major usability difference between the two options, as it seems like it comes down to personal preference. **Is there any research specifically comparing the two? Are there particular contexts where one may be stronger than the other?**

Comment: I think you are right; it will probably be personal preference, as the methods are very similar to each other. I prefer the Off-canvas method, as it does not blend in with the vertical content, and many users have familiarity with the method Facebook uses.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

An **off-canvas** design works very well with a mobile **app**, as you can hook into native swipe gestures like Facebook does to deliver the most beautiful and usable design possible.

A **dropdown**, like with Bootstrap, works well for a mobile website, as you can simply tap and an animation will run, as opposed to an off-canvas, in which you should probably code a swipe gesture for usability.  A dropdown would be your way to go.

Comment: An interesting way to distinguish -- but I also like Keiwes's point about off-canvas navigation not blending in with the vertical content. I also was under the impression that many mobile browsers do support swiping, so it may just be a matter of a little extra coding to recognize gestures.

Comment: They do, it's just that it would be vastly inferior to a native swipe method.